# AndroidManifest.xml Errors: unresolved class, attribute android:***** not allowed here

Tags: android, manifest

I asked this question already a few months back but still couldn't fix it. I am working on code someone sent me and am getting mainly two errors in my `AnroidManifest.xml` file:

For every single activity I get: `Unresolved Class '*className*'`
and for most attributes: `Attribute: android:*attribute* is not allowed here`

The package names are the same in all relevant classes and a few friends also took a look at my code and couldn't figure out the error, so I hope you can help me.

Thanks a lot in advance.

[Code and Error sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZNV2.png)

Also the start of my Manifest file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="psychosomatik.mimikapp">

    <application
        android:name=".LoginController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MenuActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".ScoreboardActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

In this sample I get the following errors:

```
 - Unresolved class 'LoginController'
 - Attribute: android:allowBackup is not allowed here
 - Attribute: android:icon is not allowed here
 - Attribute: android:supportsRtl is not allowed here
 - Attribute: android:theme is not allowed here
 - Unresolved class 'MenuActivity'
 - Unresolved class 'ScoreboardActivity'
 - Attribute: android:screenOrientation is not allowed here
```

Comment: is your `LoginController` subclassing `Application` class ?

Comment: it extends 'Application', so yes

Comment: Try to clean project then rebuild at build menu, hope this help...

Comment: Thanks, how do I exactly clean my project? I tried deleting the build.gradle file and rebuilding but that didn't help